# Converting hexadecimal to binary in java

Tags: java

I try to do:

```
String x = "He34llo";
int i = Integer.parseInt(x, 16);
String xx = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
```

But I get an `exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "He34llo"`

Comment: Do you know what hexadecimal is? (and how is it represented)

Answer (score 1):

`H`, `l` and `o` are no valid hexadecimal digits.

Answer (score 1):

Only the numbers from 0 to 9 and A,B,C,D,E,F are valid Hexadecimal Characters.

See [Wikipedia: Hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) for more information about Hexadecimal Numbers.

Comment: 0-9 are hexadecimal digits as well

Answer (score 1):

In short: Your request is imposible.

Explanation:

```
String x = "He34llo";
```

can't be converted to hexadecimal because it contains invalid digits.

Hexadecimal can have following: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E and F.

In your case invalid letters are H,l and O.

Answer (score 0):

`He34llo` is not a valid hexadecimal number, therefore you get error when trying to convert it to one.

Answer (score 0):

0 - To covert **String** ==> **Binary** try this :  (**String=> Hexa decimal ==> Decimal ==>Binary number** )

1 - Converting **String** to **Hexa decimal**  in java:

```
public String toHex(String arg) {
  return String.format("%x", new BigInteger(1, arg.getBytes(/*YOUR_CHARSET?*/)));
}
```

2 - Converting **Hexa decimal** number to **Decimal** in Java

```
int decimal = Integer.parseInt(hexadecimal, 16);
```

3 - Converting **Decimal** number to **binary** in Java

```
String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(decimal);
```

**PS : Hexadecimal can have following: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E and F.**